# Parent content with iframe in blank page?

Tags: iframe, parent

I have created a web page which for example contains some links and an iframe. These links are opened in iframe, so everything outside iframe is static (parent content doesn't reload). All works fine and all my pages are well structured so that it's easy to understand code of page.
But when I press a middle button on one of the mentioned links (to open it in a new tab or window) that isn't in iframe and normally should open in iframe, a browser will only display the content which is inside iframe and parent content will be lost.

What could be the best solution for this problem?

The only thing I need is an iframe which works as usual, targeted links are opened in it.
If a link is opened in a new tab or window, it looks the same if the link would have opened with a left click of mouse.

Comment: is it possible to get the parent/original content and iframe from previous tab/link/location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of links you can use buttons, on them right or middle click can't be performed.

Better solution. Now I'm using [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/#kebabs.html) with modified and improved initialization code.